# Setting up a repository server

Tags: apt, repository

Is it possible to set up a server to mirror a distro's repository, but only download/store requested upgrades or new packages rather than download them all?

So all computers on the LAN can connect to this server for all upgrades so they only have to be downloaded once.

I've looked at apt-mirror but that seems to download everything.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan for possible solutions. For `apt-cacher-ng` see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/46534/how-to-set-up-an-apt-cacher-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Apt Cacher or [Apt Cacher NG](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/). You can also check out the [manual for Apt Cacher NG](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/html/index.html). There's also a pretty good guide in the Ubuntu community documentation titled: [Apt-Cacher-Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server).

#### Setup

Setting it up is pretty straightforward.

1. Install

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install apt-cacher-ng
   ```
2. Test it's accessible via browser

   ```
   http://server_IP:3142
   ```
3. Add the cache to one of your systems

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
   ```
4. Add this line to your `apt.conf` file

   ```
   Acquire::http { Proxy "http://server_ip:3142"; };
   ```
5. Do an update

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```

#### References

- [HOWTO: Apt-Cacher-NG on Ubuntu](http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/howto-apt-cacher-ng-on-ubuntu/)
- [Create a Local Ubuntu Repository using Apt-Mirror and Apt-Cacher](http://www.packtpub.com/article/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-apt-cacher)